# CSS style issue for PDF in Visual force email template

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template, dynamic-visualforce, css

I have one visual force email template which sends an attachment in PDF format.
I have given style class for fields in the PDF, but the given CSS does not works for the PDF.

Please help me out.

Comment: PDF is rendered with Flying Saucer. Not all CSS styles are supported. How are you implementing the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give inline-css style not the selector way of provide class.

If using CSS class then you must specify the media type for css. Example:

```
@media print {
    p {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: blue;
    }
}
```